# How can i limit wordpress title length in my wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, trim

So i have this wordpress theme that i've buyed and i want to adapt it so it looks like blog.asana.com. For learning purpose first and because i love how it looks so i'm trying to approach the functions.

I'm struggling with different issues here but first i'm using a child theme. And i'm trying to change the title of my blog post on the main page so they are on maximum 2 lines. It looks better and since my theme use some sort of masonry display i prefer it this way.
Since i'm not too used to this sorry if my questions sound dumb.
Also since it's not my theme i'm not sure how to work stuff out. I can't seems to add stuff to functions.php without it loading forever and showing and error

I've tried using this in the child theme function.php but it didnt worked.
I've also tried in the parent theme function.php

```
function max_title_length( $title ) {
$max = 20;
if( strlen( $title ) > $max ) {
return substr( $title, 0, $max ). " &hellip;";
} else {
return $title;
}
}
```

The blog i'm talking about is blog.asana.com and my theme is blog(dot)nocturn(dot)ch

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the_title(); if this doesn't work do the same for wp_title(); it depends on what the theme uses to bring in the page title.

Tried and tested as working:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length' );
function max_title_length( $title ) {
    $max = 20;
    if( strlen( $title ) > $max ) {
        $title = substr( $title, 0, $max ) . " &hellip;";
        return $title;
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
```

This will however will edit all titles using the_title();

You can then filter what pages to target and use cases to target using a variety of WordPress functions just combine them with your JavaScript if statement with “&&”:

- is_home()
- is_frontpage()
- is_single()

More can be [found here](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=Is_&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-function).

Example:

```
If( strlen($title) > $max && is_home() ) {
```

Comment: Thanks. But if i just want to modify the title lenght on main page individual blog post excerpt this will not do it ?

Comment: Add in your code that is used to display an individual blog for me please

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to do this since i'm using a theme currently. Do you want to get the look at my website administration panel ? I can give you permissions :)

Comment: Sure message me them

Comment: There isnt any messaging system on stackoverflow no ? where can i contact you ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi think you want to show just two lines only on home page.

Use this way:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length' );
function max_title_length( $title ) {
    $max = 20;
    if( is_home() && strlen( $title ) > $max ) {
        $title = substr( $title, 0, $max ) . " &hellip;";
    }
    return $title;
}
```

This will only work on the posts page.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Should i put it in the child theme functions.php ?

Comment: This will still limit the title of things outside the scope of just the blog posts for example if he was to display the title of the homepage it and any navigation elements would still be filtered